# Matrix representation of the operator $\vec{Z}: \langle l^{'} , m^{'} | \vec{Z} | l, m \rangle $

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, angular-momentum

I know that $[L_z, z] = 0$, which means that the operators $L_z$ and $\vec{Z}$ share a common eigenspace.

So, I wonder how I can get the matrix representation of the operator $\vec{Z}$ in the eigenspace of the operator angular momentum.

Comment: You'd have to compute something like $\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^\pi d \cos \theta Y_{l^\prime, m^\prime}(\theta, \phi) z Y_{l, m}(\theta, \phi)$. Since $z = r \cos \theta$, the result will go as $\delta_{m, m^\prime}$ but not $\delta_{l, l^\prime}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noting that
$$
z=r\cos\theta = r\sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{3}} Y_{10}(\theta,\phi)\,
$$
the "matrix elements" of this operator in the angular momentum eigenstates are
$$
\langle l'm' \lvert z \rvert lm \rangle = r\sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{3}}\int d\Omega\,
Y_{l'm'}^*(\theta,\phi)Y_{10}(\theta,\phi)Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)\,,
$$
which can be evaluated using the triple-product formula,
$$
\int d\Omega\,
Y_{l_1m_1}(\theta,\phi)Y_{l_2m_2}(\theta,\phi)Y_{l_3m_3}(\theta,\phi)
=\sqrt{\frac{(2l_1+1)(2l_2+1)(2l_3+1)}{4\pi}}
\begin{pmatrix}
l_1 & l_2 & l_3 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
l_1 & l_2 & l_3 \\
m_1 & m_2 & m_3
\end{pmatrix}\,,
$$
where the $(\cdot)$ expressions are Wigner 3J symbols, which can be evaluated in, for instance, *Mathematica*.  Using this identity and the fact that $Y_{l'm'}^*(\theta,\phi) = (-1)^mY_{l'(-m')}(\theta,\phi)$, we get
\begin{align}
\langle l'm' \lvert z \rvert lm \rangle &= r\sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{3}}\int d\Omega\,
Y_{l'm'}^*(\theta,\phi)Y_{10}(\theta,\phi)Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)\\
&=r\sqrt{{(2l'+1)(2l+1)}}
\begin{pmatrix}
l' & 1 & l \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
l' & 1 & l \\
-m' & 0 & m
\end{pmatrix}\,.
\end{align}
There are explicit expressions for these 3J symbols, and they're not *too* ugly, but they're long. However, we can say that in order for this matrix element to be non-zero, \textbf{it must be that} $m=m'$.  That's implicit in the 3J symbols, and that answers the question in the OP.

---

Finally, note that we're not really done computing the matrix element, because really, we need to include the radial part of the wave function as well.  Generally speaking, if the system is spherically symmetric (i.e., the system is described by a central potential), we need just one more quantum number $n$, and we can then construct an energy eigenstate as $R_{nl}(r)Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)$. Then, the full matrix element would be
$$
\langle n'l'm' \lvert z \rvert nlm \rangle
=\sqrt{{(2l'+1)(2l+1)}}
\begin{pmatrix}
l' & 1 & l \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
l' & 1 & l \\
-m' & 0 & m
\end{pmatrix}
\int_0^{\infty}dr\,r^2\,R_{n'l'}^*(r)rR_{nl}(r)\,
$$